# security report there is no .htaccess file in private:// directory

Tags: security

I have this security report  that is constantly saying:

> Security warning: Couldn't write .htaccess file. Please create a .htaccess file in your private:// directory which contains the following lines:
>
> ```
> Deny from all
>
> #Turn off all options we don't need.
> Options None
> Options +FollowSymLinks
>
> #Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
> SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
>
> <Files *>
>   #Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
>   SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
> </Files>
>
> # If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
> <IfModule mod_php5.c>
>   php_flag engine off
> </IfModule>
> ```

I have this exact file in sites/all/default/files/private. what could be wrong?
The private folder has the permissions set to 644.

Comment: What do you have your 'Private file system path' file path set to at `/admin/config/media/file-system`?

Comment: When you say `sites/all/default/files/private` do you really mean `sites/default/files/private`?

Answer (score 5):

When you say `sites/all/default/files/private` I presume you mean `sites/default/files/private`.

I suggest deleting `sites/default/files/private/.htaccess` and setting the permissions of `sites/default/files/private` to 777 temporarily. Drupal should then be able to recreate the .htaccess file which should be exactly correct.

There are other reasons this can happen, I just can't remember off the top of my head sorry. I've had this same problem before.

Comment: Sorry yeah it's sites/default/files/private so I moved it outside drupal and my webroot